# Exc 2010 transport rule - Moderation of email to external

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I'm currently trying to comply to 1 of our organization policy: for email that contains external recipient (even just 1), send the email for moderation.

I'm aware there is a condition "sent to users that are outside the organization", but this cannot cater for case when recipients are mixed of internal and external, Exchange seems processing them separately. Under this condition the email to internal recipient will go thru and the email to external recipient will be sent for moderation. This cause a difference on receiving time between internal & external (if email approved late), and even worst if the email to external is rejected, the internal recipient thought the external recipient received the same email as well.

I need both email to internal & external to be sent for moderation if ANY recipient is external, and pure internal emails to go thru. I have gone thru the condition & exception list but don't seem able to find any to fit my case, how I hope there is a condition "when ALL the recipients...". Can this be achieved within Exchange? I don't mind if I need to create more than 1 rule

Comment: Oh my. I hope you don't have a lot of externally bound email. This seems like a less than efficient, counter-productive policy.

Comment: That's an insane policy, most likely.

Comment: Hi, actually it just applied to email that contains attachment. I know I can achieve this by condition "attachment of 0 size" so I didn't mentioned it. Sorry bout that. is there anyway to fulfill the requirements within exchange itself?